# How to include AngularJS file in grunt build with web starter kit

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm

I'm coming mainly from a CMS (Wordpress, PHP) background. I'm building a new site which will be a one-page AngularJS app. I downloaded and installed the Google web starter kit. I installed AngularJS as an nmp install. But how do I get gulp serve to include the AngularJS files in my build? I'm new to building sites with packages managers and build processes. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'include the angularjs files in my build'? Concatenate, include into htmlfile?

Comment: It would also help if you provided some code from your Gruntfile.js

Comment: Meaning when the local server runs on the index.html file there is no script tag for angular.js file. I assumed the build process would include the npm dependency as it does include the css files and other scripts. But maybe I'm not understanding how it all works.

Comment: Are you using gulp or grunt? It's not quite clear from your question. Generally, if you installed a dependency through npm, you'll still have to put a `script` tag into your HTML manually to load the dependency at runtime or create a build task that concatenates your dependencies with your own code and then load the result of that.

Answer (score 5):

Think of Google Web Starter Kit as your compiler and anything inside the `/app` folder in your project as the source code for your web app. Running `gulp` at the command line is equivalent to running the compiler to build your web app. (I'm saying `gulp`, because [that is what GWSK is using now](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/web-starter-kit/development-phases).)

Adding packages via NPM allows you to extend your **compiler**, not your web app. To add packages to your web app, you would use a tool like [Bower](http://bower.io) or add them to them "manually" to your base template. Remember that you are creating a web app that will run in the cloud, and adding packages is as easy as adding a script reference to your HTML file.

### Cloud Connection

Open `your-project/app/index.html` and add a script reference to [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading) **before** the build block. For instance in the `HEAD` of your document.

```
<head>
    <!-- ... existing head items... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Add your app implementation to the `your-project/app/scripts` folder. I recommend using sub folders for controllers, directives, etc.

Instantiate your app inside the existing `main.js` script file, e.g.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var querySelector = document.querySelector.bind(document);

  ... existing Starter Kit boilerplate...

  // Instantiate my Angular app
  angular.module('MyWebApp', [
    'myDirective',
    'pageController'
  ]).config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true
    });
  });
})();
```

Add your angular modules to the build block

```
<!-- build:js scripts/main.min.js -->
<script src="scripts/directives/my-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/img-uploader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/pageController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Run `gulp serve` to test your app locally, debug, and repeat until satisfied.

### Bower Boulevard

If you don't want to rely on a third-party CDN to serve important assets of your site, you can also make AngularJS part of your app assets, i.e. the ones you control.

First you need to extend your "compiler" (see above) to add the Bower package manager:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Configure Bower to put packages into the `my-project/app/scripts/vendor` folder, see [.bowerrc](http://bower.io/docs/config/), then initialize your project with `bower init`. To add packages to your web app, e.g. to add AngularJS run:

```
bower install angular --save
```

Add the needed vendor packages to your build block in the base template to make them part of your bundle:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/main.min.js -->
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
... other angular modules you need in your app...

<script src="scripts/directives/my-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/img-uploader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/pageController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Run `gulp serve` to test a completely local web app that you can even work on when offline.

### Alternative Ways

There are other ways to achieve the above. The Starter Kit is just that; a start. Some developers like to use a combination of NPM and [Browserify](http://browserify.org), for instance, but I don't recommend it, if you don't know/like Node.js. You could go completely manual, if you are uncomfortable with package managers, and copy things as you need them into the `scripts/vendor` folder.

Try the above two methods and see if they make sense. If not, iterate.